# Convert query in my sql to Codeigniter in two database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i really need help. I have to join two database and i have tried in my query and implemented in my local model in controller and this code goes perfectly. This is my sql query :

```
SELECT skapp.p.*, c1db_pegawai.e.eselon, c1db_pegawai.j.nama_jenis FROM skapp.ref_tunjangan_struktural p
                JOIN c1db_pegawai.r_eselon e on e.id = p.eselon_id
                JOIN c1db_pegawai.r_jenis_pegawai j on j.id = p.jenis_pegawai_id
```

And the results is this : [image: Query results]

And i implemented in Codeigniter and add this in my code :

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

in my view in localhost is working fine too. This is work because i have two database in my local and query all that two database in one localhost. But in my live server, i have two databases in separate place. I have done connect it database configuration like described in Codeigniter documentation. I have also tried this to my live server, and this is my code in my model :

```
$this->db->select('p.* as p'); 
        $this->another->select('e.eselon as e, j.nama_jenis as j');
        $this->db->from('ref_tunjangan_struktural');
        $this->another->join('r_eselon','r_eselon.id = ref_tunjangan_struktural.eselon_id');
        $this->another->join('r_jenis_pegawai','r_jenis_pegawai.id = ref_tunjangan_struktural.jenis_pegawai_id');
        $this->db->order_by("ref_tunjangan_struktural.id", "asc");
```

and this is my controller for database connections :

```
    $this->load->database('default',TRUE);  //first DB
    $this->another = $this->load->database('pegawai',TRUE); //second DB
```

but i have an error results on my live server. 
`$this->another` 
is my query for second database. But still have an error. Please anyone can help me to fix in my live server model?

And this my error?

```
Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as p FROM ref_tunjangan_struktural as p ORDER BY ref_tunjangan_struktural' at line 1 SELECT p.* as p` FROM ref_tunjangan_struktural as p ORDER BY ref_tunjangan_struktural.id ASC
```

Comment: `But still have an error.` ... what is the error?

Comment: Database error accured. Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `p` FROM `ref_tunjangan_struktural` as `p` ORDER BY `ref_tunjangan_struktural' at line 1

SELECT `p`.* as `p` FROM `ref_tunjangan_struktural` as `p` ORDER BY `ref_tunjangan_struktural`.`id` ASC

Comment: first of all - show the kind of error, and second -i don't know anything about your structure - Codeigniter doesn't have a built in object called `another` - so in other word `$this->another` is not a Codeigniter QueryBuilder `object`.

Comment: sorry, this is my controller. And i declare $this-another as a second connections datbase :
$this->load->database('default',TRUE);
$this->another = $this->load->database('pegawai',TRUE);

Answer (score 0):

Should this solve your problem:

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->another->select('e.eselon as e, j.nama_jenis as j');
$this->db->from('ref_tunjangan_struktural'); 
$this->another->join('r_eselon','r_eselon.id = ref_tunjangan_struktural.eselon_id'); 
$this->another->join('r_jenis_pegawai','r_jenis_pegawai.id = ref_tunjangan_struktural.jenis_pegawai_id');
$this->db->order_by("ref_tunjangan_struktural.id", "asc");
```

Comment: it works, but cannot recall value 'eselon' as it's value. Like my query in mysql above, it cannot return 'eselon' as eselon. Just id

Comment: $this->db->select('ref_tunjangan_struktural.* '); how about this?

Comment: Still the same. Cannot return eselon as name like my query aboce. Only view as eselon_id and jenis_pegawai_id

Comment: There is no select table method from another db like $this->another->from("your table name") ???

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that - you can't mix 2 QueryBuilder Objects to create one Query

> The only thing you can do is to use your first DB instance in order to
>   connect to the other database - but this has one condition - your User
>   from your first DB has to have access to the second one - there is
>   simply no other possibility

under the given conditions - the following should work

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('skapp.p.*,c1db_pegawai.e.eselon, c1db_pegawai.j.nama_jenis')
    ->from('skapp.ref_tunjangan_struktural p')
    ->join('c1db_pegawai.r_eselon e', 'e.id = p.eselon_id')
    ->join('c1db_pegawai.r_jenis_pegawai j', 'j.id = p.jenis_pegawai_id')
    ->get();

print_r($query->result());
```

Comment: this is similiar to my query as my sql above. All i want if any other way possible to logicaly express that condition in my model

Comment: as i already said - you can't combine two different QueryBuilder instances - its simply not possible...